# Perl - PHP : random string generation

Tags: php, perl, random

I don't know perl language, but i am trying to customize an application written in perl language. I want to know the logic or meaning of the following perl code. I know this code is for generating a random string, but i want its details i.e i want to know how can i generate this same random string in PHP? Please anyone give me the PHP code for this perl code!!

```
   sub generate_rand_string {

    #warn "generate_rand_string";

    my $chars = shift
      || 'aAeEiIoOuUyYabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789';
    my $num = shift || 1024;

    require Digest::MD5;

    my @chars = split '', $chars;
    my $ran;
    for ( 1 .. $num ) {
        $ran .= $chars[ rand @chars ];
    }
    return Digest::MD5::md5_hex($ran);
}
```

Please anyone help me!!!!

Comment: "same random string" not very random if you can recreate it. so not really sure what you want.

Comment: @Dagon: Pretty sure he just wants the same functionality.

Comment: yup ok, i buy that, the 1024 chars is way over kill md5(mt_rand()); would probably do, or   md5(uniqid());

Comment: @Dagon is right. If you're returning only the md5 hash, then the process of generating a random string first - of *any* length - is a waste and *reduces* the randomess of the output. Just pick a single random number and generate its md5 hash. In Perl: `return md5_hex(rand);`

Comment: What are you doing with this "random string"?  I smell a use for a UUID.  https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Uuid

Answer (score 1):

Steps for emulating:

1. accept a string and default to `aAeEiIoOuUyYabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789` if no
   string is provided
2. accept a number and default to `1024` if no number is provided
3. split the string into characters
4. create a string with random characters selected from the above set of characters
5. return the hexadecimal representation of the MD5 hash of the string

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it would like this:

```
function generate_rand_string($chars = null, $length = 1024) {
    if($chars == null) {
        $chars = 'aAeEiIoOuUyYabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789';
    }

    $rand = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $rand .= $chars[ rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1) ];
    }

    return md5($rand);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use `array_rand()`?

Comment: the original perl din't, so this is just an attempt to be as close as possible, not saying its the best way to get a random md5 string

Comment: No why? `$chars` is only a string. It of course isn't beautiful the way it is, but he just wanted it translated to PHP.